# Rails4 simple_form reload page issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Development Environment : Rails 4, Gem Simple_form
I make this form page.
 I want to Convert button clicked under 2 forms fill Address to longitude and latitude.
(Convert button click -> under two forms fill the longitude and latitude)

[image]

But Convert button clicked -> load this page

[image]

Sometimes that is working

[image]
This is my code.

View file

```
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.input :name, label: "상호명" %>
      <%= form.input :address, label: "주소" %>
      <button name="convert_address" type=button" id="convert_address">Convert</button>
      <%= form.input :longitude, label: "경도" %>
      <%= form.input :latitude, label: "위도" %>
      <%= form.input :phone, label: "전화번호" %>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= form.button :submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

JS file(Hide my apikey)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.convertAddress = function (query, obj1, obj2, position) {
        var url = "http://apis.daum.net/local/geo/addr2coord?apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&q=" + encodeURI(query) + "&output=json";
        $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", function (data) {
          $.each(data.channel.item, function (i, item) {
              if (position == 1) {
                  obj1.val(item.point_y);
                  obj2.val(item.point_x);
              } else if (position == 2) {
                  obj1.value = item.point_y;
                  obj2.value = item.point_x;
              }
          });
      });

  }

$("#menu-toggle").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("active");
});
$("#convert_address").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("test");
    $.convertAddress($("#store_address").val(), $("#store_latitude"), $("#store_longitude"), 1);
});
```

})

application.js

```
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   //= require admin/menus_js.js
   //= require admin/stores_js.js
   //= require bootstrap
   //= require bootstrap-sprockets
   //= require turbolinks
   //= require_tree .
```

controller

```
def create
  @store = Store.new(params.require(:store).permit(:name, :address, :phone, :longitude, :latitude))
  if @store.save
    redirect_to "/admin/stores"
  else
    render "/admin/stores/new"
  end
end
```

rake routes

[image]

Routes.rb

```
   namespace :admin do 
     resources :stores
     root 'stores#index'
   end
```

I am really sorry that don't speak english very well...
Thanks!